# sort multiple tabs but ignoring spaces

Tags: bash, unix, sorting, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a data file like this (\t represents tabs):

```
short line\t    \t    \t    \t    \t    3
very long line with lots of text\t\t    2
```

How could I sort it by the second column using sort?  In other words I want to set the delimiter to be multiple tabs, but not spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the field separator for `sort` must be a single character, so this command:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k2 file
```

will not handle multiple tabs as a single separator: it will sort the empty 2nd field for both lines.

This command will successfully find the the second field, but it modifies the text:

```
tr -s '\t' < file | sort -t $'\t' -k2
```

Note that `tr` interprets the 2-character string "\t" as a tab character, while `sed -t` does not. Just a foible of how different commands are implemented.

Comment: This works for me.  I then use something like this to re-format the output into aligned columns:  awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\t"};{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%-20s", $i); printf "\n"}'

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -k2 -t'        ' test.txt
```

worked out of the box for me. Enter the TAB inside `'    '` as <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> in bash

Comment: Although this works on my linux box, it doesn't work on my cygwin box. :(

Comment: That's interesting. I tested it on... cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Setting the field delimiter to something else is accomplished with the **-t** parameter. But passing a tab character can be tricky, so the solution may look like:

> sort -t "$(echo -e '\t')" -k 2 file.txt

Comment: I can see this would work if the echo were enclosed in $(...) to produce the tab.  However, I think the CTRL-V tab solution is easier.

Comment: Yes, initially I used the single quote character that Stackoverflow did not display. Now I changed it to the alternative $(..) notation.

Comment: The Ctrl+V solutions assumes you are using a specifically configured terminal (that interprets this combination as insert of tab and not pressing the key). The solution can also cause troubles if you are copy/pasteing it around (eg. in a terminal that converts tabs to spaces and then back again). Problems can also arise if you try to use it in a script file and use weird editors.